# Shell Script: grep and replace

Tags: shell, sed, grep

I have a file "**test.htm**" with the follwoing content

```
<html>

<head></head>

<body>site-is-down</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to make it "site-is-up" if it has text "site-is-down".
When I execute the script its showing correct output ,but its not replacing anything in the file

```
 #!/bin/ksh
if grep "site-is-down" test.htm; then
 sed -e "s/down/up/g" test.htm
else
 echo "Site is already up"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
sed -e "s/down/up/g" test.htm
```

To this:

```
sed -i -e "s/down/up/g" test.htm
```

The `-i` flag means to edit the file "in-place" rather than to write the replacements to standard output.

Answer (score 0):

To replace every occurrence of a certain word / string in a ton of files spanning multiple directories, and this is the quickest way I've found to do it. It uses grep to search for a certain word and if it find its it runs sed to replace the strings you want.

```
grep -rl matchstring somedir/ | xargs sed -i 's/string1/string2/g'
```